# How to sync the data through online API data to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

The is an third party site that store the videos, I would like to copy some data to my database, and create a sync button.

The video record will not update, therefore, when sync the data only insert and delete is needed

The insert is implement like this

```
    public function add_brightcove($offset = 0) {
        $videos = cms_get_video_list($offset);

        foreach ($videos as $v) {
                $data_insert = array(
                    "video_id" => $v->id,
                    "title" => $v->original_filename,
                    "duration" => $v->duration,
                    "thumbnail" => $v->images->poster->src,
                    "is_active" => 1
                );

                $sql = $this->db->insert_string('brightcove', $data_insert) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE video_id=video_id';
                $this->db->query($sql);
            }
        }

if (count($videos == 100)) {
            $this->add_brightcove($offset + 100);
        }

}
```

The API only get 100 record per time , so I use recursive function to recall the same function to get the rest of the data.

Right now it need to run through  the list for first time to handle insert , and the second time to handle the delete

the problem is how to handle the delete, in a more performance way?

Thanks for helping

Comment: possibly you could use `insert ignore....`

Comment: Please explain what the `DELETE` needs to do.